# ASP.NET Core Razor Pages, passing viewData to partial view

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor-pages

Let's say I want to pass in a `product` card to my partial view. I would like to pass the `product` model into the partial view as well as some non-model variables that will basically just add on classes for `css` styling on individual cards. I have passed in my product model and the non-model variables `classList`, `isFeatured`, and `isBestSelling` via the partial tag helper code below

```
@for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) 
{
    var classList = new List<string>();
    var isFeatured = i == 0;
    var isBestSelling = i == 1 || i == 2;

    if (isFeatured)
    {
        classList.Add(@"border");
        classList.Add(@"border-secondary");
    } 
    else if (isBestSelling) 
    {
        classList.Add(@"border");
        classList.Add(@"border-success");
    }

    var product = Model.Products[i];

    <div class="col-12 col-tablet-6 col-laptop-4 col-desktop-3 my-3">
        <partial name="_ProductCardPartial" model="product" view-data='new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData){ { "isBestSelling", isBestSelling }, { "isFeatured", isFeatured }, { "classList", classList } }'/>
    </div>
}
```

How can I access that `ViewData` on the partial as its model is not the index page that contains the `ViewData` and I am not passing that in as its model. I have looked at examples from [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-6.0#access-data-from-partial-views). And they are just using the new `ViewData` dictionary they passed in to the partial view no problem, which doesn't work for me.

I have tried initializing a new instance of the `Index` type (which holds the `PageModel` and inherited `ViewData`) in the partial and setting variables from the view data like so:

```
@{
    var data = new Index();
    bool isFeatured = (bool)data.ViewData["isFeatured"];
    bool classList = (bool)data.ViewData["classList"];
    bool isBestSelling = (bool)data.ViewData["isBestSelling"];
}
```

Yes I have the correct using statement to use this type. I get this error when building still

> Error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'RazorPageBase.WriteLiteral(object?)

I have tried to just use the entire path to the Index PageModel like so:

```
Pages.Pages_Index.ViewData["isFeatured"]
```

and then I get the following error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Pages_Index.ViewData'

At this point I am not sure how I can reference the variables inside the partial view.

Comment: Just create a new model for the partial view that has all to properties the partial view needs.  Then create an instance of that class and pass that as the model to the partial view

Comment: That is a valid workaround, but is there no way to accomplish this without creating a new model

Comment: I dont see it as a workaround. It is appropriate to have a model specific for a partial view.  As in my opinion is the right way to go.

Comment: Have you tried accessing view data simply like: `ViewData["isFeatured"]`?

Comment: Yes, and since ViewData isnt on the product model, I cannot access it that way. The ViewData being passed into the partial is of type Index.PageModel (the parent view's code behind).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ViewData` dictionary is not related to the model.

Example:

**Index.cshtml**

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

@foreach(var product in Model.Products)
{
    <partial name="_ProductPartial"
             model="product"
             view-data='@new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData) { { "Param1", "abc" }, { "Param2", "def" } }' />
}
```

**_ProductPartial.cshtml**

```
@model Product

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">

        <p>@ViewData["Param1"]</p>
        <p>@ViewData["Param2"]</p>

        <p>@Model.Id</p>
        <p>@Model.Name</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

I created a small demo project on [github](https://github.com/Jimmys20/RazorPagesViewDataPartial) . It works as expected.

Comment: Do you know why in my project when I create a partial view it says that the name Model does not exist in the context?

many thanks for the help